# Replacing a set of words in a large text file

Tags: python, optimization, nlp, bigdata

I have a large txt file(around 20GB) I want to replace all instances of a list of words from this large file. I am struggling to find a way to optimize this code. This is leading to me processing this file for a very long time.

what could I improve ?

```html
    corpus_input =  open(corpus_in,"rt")
    corpus_out = open(corpus_out,"wt")
    for line in corpus_input:
        temp_str=line
        for word in dict_keys:
            if word in line:
                new_word = word+"_lauren_ipsum"
                temp_str = re.sub(fr'\b{word}\b',new_word,temp_str)

            else:
                continue
        
        corpus_out.writelines(temp_str)

     corpus_input.close()
     corpus_out.close()
```

Comment: please add following information to your question.

About how many words are in dict_keys?
roughly how often does a word exist in a line?
every 50th line / every 10th line every line?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. How much faster is your solution after all modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing for optimisation is to understand, what exactly is performing poorly.
Then you can see what can be optimized.

If for example reading and writing takes 99% of the time it's not really worth to optimize the processing of your data.
Even if you could speed up the processing by 10 you would just gain 0.9% if reading writing were consuming 99%

I suggest to measure and compare some versions and to post differences in performance.
This might lead potential further suggestions to optimise.

**In all below examples I replaced `writelines` with `write`** as writelines is probably decomposing your line character by character prior to writing.

In any case. You want to use **`write`**
You should already gain a speedup of about 5.

1.) Just reading and writing

```
with open(corpus_in,"rt") as corpus_input, open(corpus_out,"wt")
 as corpus_out:
   for line in corpus_input:
       corpus_out.write(line)
```

2.) Just reading and writing
 with a bigger buffer

```
import io

BUF_SIZE = 50 * io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE # try other buffer sizes if you see an impact
with open(corpus_in,"rt", BUF_SIZE) as corpus_input, open(corpus_out,"wt", BUF_SIZE)
 as corpus_out:
   for line in corpus_input:
corpus_out.write(line)
```

For me this increases performance by a few percent

3.) move search regexp and replacement generation out of loop.

```
   rules = []
   for word in dict_keys:
       rules.append((re.compile(fr'\b{word}\b'), word + "_lorem_ipsum"))

   for line in corpus_input:
       for regexp, new_word in rules: 
           line = regexp.sub(new_word, line)
       corpus_out.write(line)
```

On my machine with my frequency of lines containing words this solution is in fact slower then the one having the line `if word in line`

So perhaps try:
3.a) move search regexp and replacement generation out of loop.

```
   rules = []
   for word in dict_keys:
       rules.append((word, re.compile(fr'\b{word}\b'), word + "_lorem_ipsum"))

   for line in corpus_input:
       for word, regexp, new_word in rules: 
           if word in line:
               line = regexp.sub(new_word, line)
       corpus_out.write(line)
```

3.b) If all replacement strings are longer than the initial strings, then this would be a little faster.

```
   rules = []
   for word in dict_keys:
       rules.append((word, re.compile(fr'\b{word}\b'), word + "_lorem_ipsum"))

   for line in corpus_input:
       temp_line = line
       for word, regexp, new_word in rules: 
           if word in line:
               temp_line = regexp.sub(new_word, temp_line)
       corpus_out.write(temp_line)
```

4.) if you really replace always with `word + "_lorem_ipsum"` combine the regular expression into one.

```
   regexp = re.compile(fr'\b({"|".join(dict_keys)})\b')

   for line in corpus_input:
       line = regexp.sub("\1_lorem_ipsum", line)
       corpus_out.write(line)
```

4.a) depending on the word distribution this might be faster:

```
   regexp = re.compile(fr'\b({"|".join(dict_keys)})\b')

   for line in corpus_input:
       if any(word in line for word in dict_keys):
           line = regexp.sub("\1_lorem_ipsum", line)
       corpus_out.write(line)
```

Whether this is more efficient or not depends probably on the number of words to search and replace and the frequency of thise words.
I don't have that date.

For 5 words and my distribution slower than 3.a

5) if the words to replace are different you might still try to combine the regexps and use a function to replace

```
   replace_table = {
      "word1": "word1_laram_apsam",
      "word2": "word2_lerem_epsem",
      "word3": "word3_lorom_opsom",

   }

   def repl(match):
      return replace_table[match.group(1)]

   regexp = re.compile(fr'\b({"|".join(dict_keys)})\b')

   for line in corpus_input:
       line = regexp.sub(repl, line)
       corpus_out.write(line)
```

Slower than 5, whether better than 3.a depends on number of words and wird distribution / frequency.

Comment: I made some preliminary tests. not knowing the data, the number of words to look for.
the frequency of words makes it difficult to know what can be optimized.

without further info 3.a seems to be the best solution (at least for my data)

Comment: added 4.b scenario (perhaps faster than 3.a or 3.b)

Comment: So I ran a code profile and the writing to the file was the most taxing function in my code.

Comment: OK,  You might add this information and percentages in your question.  Please see in my answer, that I replaced `corpus_out.writelines()` with `corpus_out.write()`, which gave at least on my machine a considerable performance boost ( > 5x)

Increasing the buffer size improved performance also by a few percent.

With suggestion 3b you also improve perf by preparing the regexp and the word to replace out if the loop

Comment: also if you have time. Could you comment what was in your case the fastest solution?
THis might help others reading this question lateron